# Recursive fetch/promise to prevent timeout during potentially long backend processing

Tags: javascript, recursion, syntax, promise, timeout

When my web server validates new WiFi settings, validation ends quickly if the credentials are good but takes a while to time out if they're not. I'd like to hold up the user for as short a time as possible when validation succeeds while preventing the browser from timing out when it takes longer.

I found an example of recursive fetch/promise calls that seems like it should work but it doesn't.

Does anyone see what I'm missing?

```
<html><head>
<script>const fetchWithRetry = (ThisURL) => {
let abort = false;
const options = {
  url: ThisURL,
  options: {},
  cancel: {},
  retries: 30,
  retryDelay: 1000
};

// Add an abort to the cancel object.
cancel.abort = () => { abort = true };

// Abort or proceed?
return abort ? Promise.reject('aborted') : fetch(options.url).then(response => {

  // Reject because of abort
 return abort ? Promise.reject('aborted')

  // Response is good 
  : response.ok ? Promise.resolve(response.text()) 

  // Retries exceeded
  : !options.retries ? Promise.reject('retries exceeded')

  // Retry with one less retry
  : new Promise((resolve, reject){
      setTimeout(() => {

        // We use the returned promise's resolve and reject as
        // callback so that the nested call propagates backwards.
        fetchWithRetry({ ThisURL, retries: retries - 1 }).then(resolve, reject);
      }, options.retryDelay);

    });
  });
}</script>
<title>'Verifying WiFi Settings'</title>
</head>
<body onload="fetchWithRetry('/WiFiValid')">
<h1>Please wait while WiFi settings are verified</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, you have some syntax errors. `new Promise((resolve, reject){` is missing the `=>`. and `cancel.abort` is undefined. Maybe you mean `options.cancel.abort`? You are also passing an object to `fetchWithRetry` toward the end, but it looks like `fetchWithRetry` just wants a URL.

Comment: besides the above problem ... cancel.abort is never called, so abort is never true - and this is way more complex than it needs to be

Comment: See if [this code](https://pastebin.com/ka9Y3gJD) works better for you

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I collapsed it as shown below, ran it and Chrome tells me there's an

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ran it and Chrome tells me there's an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token throw in SaveSettings:9. If it's counting \n's to determine line number, that means it's here: [new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(reject, timeout,'timeout')),